# tr / td stretching when a lot of text is added

Tags: html, css

My td / tr is stretching VERTICALLY when a lot of text is added. I need the row to stay the same size no matter how much text is displayed (scrollable if overflown)

```
table {
  display: inline-block;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-top: none;
}
tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  max-height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
}
td {
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  overflow-y: none;
  max-height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  overflow-x: scroll
}
```

Comment: how many td in a tr ?

Comment: 7 per row @Anuresh

Answer (score 0):

How about adding

```
 td {
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  max-height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  width: 14.28%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

to your css.